# Difference between 合意、納得、相互理解？

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I was wondering what the difference is between 合意、納得、相互理解?

Answer (score 1):

Direct translations by the word themselves are

合意 both opinions are match(agreement)
納得 understand
相互理解 understand each other

But as you know words have many meanings with its context so you/we might need more info.